# In nUnit, what is the equivalent to Hamcrest's Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(Matcher... matchers)?

Tags: java, c#, nunit, hamcrest

I'd like to assert that an ICollection contains items that will satisfy a collection of Constraints. For Java Hamcrest, I would use Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(Matcher... matchers). That is for a given collection, each item of the collection would match one matcher in matchers.

I'm struggling to find an equivalent in nUnit 3. Does one exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. I implemented a slick answer to this. The key is to create an IComparer that will compare the constraint and the object. It looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// A Comparer that's appropriate to use when wanting to match objects with expected constraints.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="System.Collections.IComparer" />
public class ConstraintComparator : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var constraint = x as IConstraint;

        var matchResult = constraint.ApplyTo(y);

        return matchResult.IsSuccess ? 0 : -1;
    }
}
```

I can then do the following:

```
Assert.That(actual, Is.EquivalentTo(constraints).Using(new ConstraintComparator()));
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the CollectionEquivalentConstraint,

> CollectionEquivalentConstraint tests that two IEnumerables are equivalent - that they contain the same items, in any order. If the actual value passed does not implement IEnumerable an exception is thrown.

```
int[] iarray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
string[] sarray = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
Assert.That( new string[] { "c", "a", "b" }, Is.EquivalentTo( sarray ) );
Assert.That( new int[] { 1, 2, 2 }, Is.Not.EquivalentTo( iarray ) );
```

If you need more details, check out the docs at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/CollectionEquivalentConstraint

Comment: That almost does what I want. But it's not quite the same thing. With CollectionEquivalentConstraints, I give it a collection of objects to compare against. It then checks to see if there exists one item in the expected that is equal to one item in the actual for each object. I want to use a collection of IConstraint objects instead. So that for each object in the actual, it asserts to true for one item in the expected matchers.

To give an example, let's say I have the array int[] { 1, 2 } and I want to assert that this is an array of two objects that has exactly one odd and one even.